# Nested dimensions in macro array argument

Tags: vba, for-loop, indexing, ms-word

I am providing a multi-dimensional array to a macro in Word. Each element is an array, and each array element has 2 values, the name of an image and a short description. The macro is:

```
For i = LBound(figures, 1) To UBound(figures, 1)
    cgmImage = "C:\path\to\images\" & figures(i, 0) & ".jpeg"
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=cgmImage, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    With Selection
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .TypeText Text:=figures(i, 1)
    End With
Next i
```

Sample input array would be:

```
[
    ['123','image 1'],
    ['456','image 2']
]
```

The macro works, inserting each image and its description. However I now want to add a third element, this element will itself be a 2D array representing a table. So input will look something like this:

```
[
    [ '123','image 1', [['val1','val2'],['val3','val4']] ],
    [ '456','image 2', [['val1','val2'],['val3','val4']] ]
]
```

In the macro I'll use this 3rd element to create a table. However, if I give input data like that into my original macro I now get a 'subscript out of range' error on this line:

```
cgmImage = "C:\path\to\images\" & figures(i, 0) & ".jpeg"
```

All I want to iterate is the first level of this whole data structure (e.g. for the sample data I provided above, 2 iterations). Even if I provide the 'dimension' attribute to `LBound` and `UBound` I still get the error, which shouldn't happen since the first element of the top level array elements are always just a string (the image file name). How can I achieve this? And will accessing the third element representing the table be along the lines of :`figures(i,2,X,X)`?

EDIT:

Array creation is in Python, just a standard list type. Calling of the macro is done using the [mhammond pywin32 module](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) here's a simplified version of the technique:

```
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
template = word.Documents.Open("\path\to\file.docm")
word.Run("macroName",imagesArray)
```

Then I save and close it

Comment: How are you creating the array?  Through code?  If Yes then it would help to include that (and any other relevant lines)

Comment: I'm extracting it from an XML file in a Python script (just a standard list data type), then running the macro using the pywin32 module using that array as an argument. I've added the code above.

Comment: does `figures(i)(0)` work? array indexing in VBA is different to Python.

Comment: If you look at the array in the Watches window does it look as expected?

Comment: Yes the array looks as expected. Ok using `figures(i)(0)` the first 2 elements now work again and that error is gone. Weird cos I use the other notation in another macro for a 2D array argument and it works fine....anyways, I still can't access the third 2D array element, neither with `figures(i)(2)(0)(0)` nor `figures(i)(2)(0, 0)`, those statements now give the subscript range error.

Comment: I can’t test it but you could try first setting a helper array variable (Dim tempArray As Variant; tempArray=figures(i)(2)) and then use it (tempArray(1,1)).

Comment: Had a more thorough look through the watch window, turns out even though all the arrays are the same structure in the Python output, in the VBA macro some are accessed via `figures(1)(2)(0)(0)` while others are accessed via `figures(1)(2)(0, 0)`. Don't know why it differentiated identical input lists.

Answer (score 0):

if the inner most array is an array of array, then something like `figures(i)(j)(k)(l)` should be the way to go

you can use `UBound(array,index)` and `LBound(array,index`) functions to get the actual lower and upper array bounds of its `index` dimension

for example, along the lines of data you shown, you could consider the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim figures(1) As Variant

    figures(0) = Array("123", "image 1", Array(Array("val1", "val2"), Array("val3", "val4"))) ' see how the innermost array is an array of arrays, too
    figures(1) = Array("456", "image 2", Array(Array("val5", "val6"), Array("val7", "val8"))) ' see how the innermost array is an array of arrays, too

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
    For i = LBound(figures) To UBound(figures)
        For j = LBound(figures(i)) To UBound(figures(i))
            If IsArray(figures(i)(j)) Then
                For k = LBound(figures(i)(j)) To UBound(figures(i)(j))
                    For l = LBound(figures(i)(j)(k)) To UBound(figures(i)(j)(k))
                        Debug.Print figures(i)(j)(k)(l)
                    Next
                Next
            Else
                Debug.Print figures(i)(j)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Alrighty I can't check on my home comp I'll check it out on Monday and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I get a 'Subscript out of range' error on the lin `For l = LBound(figures(i)(j)(k)) To UBound(figures(i)(j)(k))`.

Comment: Must be handling the input Python array different than normal arrays. Though it works perfectly fine for the higher level arrays...

Comment: Ooooookay so I looked through every element of the input data in the VBA watch window. Turns out for the 2D table elements, the first one is indexed like this: `figures(1)(2)(0)(0)`, but the others are indexed like this: `figures(2)(2)(0,0)`. They are all created the exact same way in the Python script so why they're indexed differently in VBA I have no idea.